# Foreach loop with 2d array of objects

Tags: xna, c#, objects

I'm using a 2D array of objects to store data about tiles, or "blocks" in my gameworld. I initialise the array, fill it with data and then attempt to invoke the draw method of each object.

```
foreach (Block block in blockList)
  {
    block.Draw(spriteBatch);
  }
```

I end up with an exception being thrown "Object reference is not set to an instance of an object".

What have I done wrong?

**EDIT:**
This is the code used to define the array

```
Block[,] blockList;
```

Then

```
blockList = new Block[screenRectangle.Width, screenRectangle.Height];
  // Fill with dummy data
  for (int x = 0; x <= screenRectangle.Width / texture.Width; x++)
  {
    for (int y = 0; y <= screenRectangle.Height / texture.Width; y++)
    {
      if (y >= screenRectangle.Height / (texture.Width*2))
      {
        blockList[x, y] = new Block(1, new Rectangle(x * 16, y * 16, texture.Width, texture.Height), texture);
      }
      else
      {
        blockList[x, y] = new Block(0, new Rectangle(x * 16, y * 16, texture.Width, texture.Height), texture);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a list. You've forgotten to prepopulate / structure it correctly.

Maybe you created your list so:

```
List<List<Block>> blockList = new ArrayList<List<Block>>();
//OR
ArrayList blockList = new ArrayList(); //older, non-generic ArrayList
```

Remember that a standard 1D list looks like this:

`0|1|2|3`

In your case you've created a list of lists, so you have this:

`0[]|1[]|2[]|3[]`

The square brackets represent the inner lists (of blocks) that sit within each outer list element. To clarify, when indexing your 2D list that would be `blockList[outerIndex][innerIndex]`, which would return you a block, whereas just calling `blockList[outerIndex]` *should* return you a list of blocks. However, that is probably returning `null`, and the reason is as follows...

When you create the outer array (a list of lists), C# does not implicitly create the inner lists. You need to first declare and construct the outer list `blockList` as shown above, and then before you do any real work you need to initialise that by doing

```
for (int i = 0; i < desiredNumOfRowsPerColOrColsPerRow; i++)
{
    blockList.Add(new ArrayList<Block>());
}
```

If you had chosen to use a fixed size 2D array (`Block[,] blockArray`) you would not have experienced this problem.

Comment: Actually, I AM using a fixed size 2D array. I've updated the original question with the declaration code.

Comment: Before the edit, you'd stated that this was a list. Have you tested the spritebatch for `null`ness using a trace? Because it's either the list or the spritebatch. Either way, once you find the null, work your way back from there.

Comment: @JacobMillwrad I notice you have "screenRectangle.Height / texture.Width". Is your texture the same width and height?

Comment: Yup, just a simple 16x16 texture. And I stated it was an array, however I've called it blockList. Confusing I know.

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it myself by using:
for (int x = 0; x <= screenRectangle.Width / texture.Width; x++)
      {
        for (int y = 0; y <= screenRectangle.Height / texture.Width; y++)
        {
          blockList[x, y].Draw(spriteBatch);
        }
      }

Comment: @JacobMillward Glad its sprted. Cheers for the accept.

Answer (score -2):

I see three alternatives:

- or blockList is null
- or blocklist contains null values...
- or blocklist contains values that are not of type block

I'd test with this code:

```
foreach (Block block in blockList)
{
  if (block == null)
  { 
      System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
  }
  block.Draw(spriteBatch);
}
```

Comment: ¿-1? you should say why...